# Make API calls asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having troubles understand how to attack the problem I have at hand.

I have a website with a lot of products, and to fill these pages with products I call a method from my API provider called `GetProducts`. This works well, but I would like to speed this process up by splitting this request up into smaller request and run them asynchronously. The `GetProducts` method offers a `pageNumber`parameter, which I can do to make sure I'm getting different pages of records.

So, I've tried different ways of solving this but I'm not getting anywhere. Code example:

```
int n = 0;
var tasks = new List<Task>();

// this method gets the total amount of products for the category
totalAmountOfProducts = MyApi.GetProductsCount(category);

while (n < totalAmountOfProducts / 200)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        tasks.Add(GetProductsAsync(category, i, 200));
    }

    n += i;
    Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    var totalProducts = // add products from the last 10 iterations to total in some way
}

private async Task<ProductList> GetProductsAsync(string category, int pageNumber, int productAmount)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => MyApi.GetProducts(category, pageNumber, productAmount))
}
```

How do I go about this? I've tried three different versions but they all end up with errors or doing... nothing. But I realize this is completely wrong... For example, I'm running `await` in the `GetProductsAsync` method, which ruins the purpose of the `Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray())` line, if I'm understanding correctly, but it was the only way to get rid of all the error messages saying that the type `ProductList` couldn't be converted to `System.Action`.

Comment: It looks like you are not doing anything with `GetProductsAsync(category, i, 200)` result.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Parallel.ForEach`, optionally with a custom partitioner. `async` is for asynchrony, not (primarily) parallelism, and you won't have a very good time with the kind of async-over-sync wrapper demonstrated here even if you do get it to work.

Comment: @Fildor Sorry, miswrote when copying over the code. Fixed it.
@Jeroen Mostert hmm... I was thinking they're about the same thing? Will definitely look into `Parallel.ForEach` though!

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is more appropriate for things that don't return results, because if they do you have to manually collate stuff again -- I meant PLINQ and `Enumerable.AsParallel`. Always confusing those. :-P There's also the TPL dataflow library, which integrates better with tasks, but is a bit of work for something as simple as this.

Comment: If user can't see all products at once, you can load only those that are visible + a small offset.

Answer (score 2):

You should put await keyword in front of Task.WhenAll:

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

If you don't await the task, the code will execute assignment statement var totalProducts = .. synchronously when the task has not completed, which will has no result or throw an exception.

Comment: We don't know *what* that code will do, because the code isn't shown.  Maybe it'll synchronously wait, maybe it'll get the results asynchronously, maybe it will get the wrong results because the tasks haven't finished, there's just no way to say without seeing the code.